# Python 3.x to Productivity 2000 PLC Communication

Tags: python-3.x, plc

I want to communicate with a PLC (specifically the Productivity 2000) using python. I have found cpppo and pycomm; the problem is that these are made for python2. What is my best alternative that can be used in python3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest CPPPO library supports Python 3.

https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo

The Productivity 2000 PLC also supports Modbus TCP. There are several python libraries for this protocol as well.

https://github.com/sourceperl/pyModbusTCP
https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus